# Object called undefined in inner nested Callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

"First" is printed along with Object t being printed normally but the Callback after that Callback is entered "Second" is printed along with t being printed as undefined. In the applied(t) function an error -TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined- is caused because Object t is for some reason undefined at this point. What could be the cause of this if it was not undefined prior to entering this Callback function? update() is a MongoDB function.

```
function applied(t)
{
    this.transactions.update(
    {
        _id: t._id, state: "pending" },
    {
        $set: { state: "applied" },
        $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
    }
)
}

function applytransaction(t,f,fb)
{

    x=fb(t.value);
    y=f(t.value);

    this.model.update(

    { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
    { $inc: { bal:x }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
    , function(err,t,y) {
        console.log("First "+t);
        this.model.update(
            { _id: t.destination, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
            { $inc: { bal: y }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
         , function(err, t) {
             console.log("Second " +t);
            applied(t);
        });

    });


}
```

Comment: You have too many variables named `t`. Give them unique names. For that matter, stop using 1 and 2 letter variable names and give all of your variables meaningful names.

Comment: So the second update fails, clearly `t` isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

> Object t is for some reason undefined at this point. What could be the cause of this if it was not undefined prior to entering this Callback function? update() is a MongoDB function.

The cause is that the `t` inside your first callback (and the second one) are different from the first `t`. Give them unique names and check for errors and you should find out what the problem is.

**Update based on your comment**: If you want to use the original `t` throughout your function, then just use it. Don't expect it to somehow come out of the callback parameters because [according to the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html), the second value passed to the callbacks is the number of records updated, not whatever `t` is.

```
function applytransaction(t, f, fb)
{
    x = fb(t.value);
    y = f(t.value);

    this.model.update(
        { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
        { $inc: { bal:x }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } },
        function(err1, count1, status1) {
            console.log("First err:", err1);
            console.log("First ", t);

            this.model.update(
                { _id: t.destination, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
                { $inc: { bal: y }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } },
                function(err2, count2) {
                    console.log("Second err", err2);
                    console.log("Second ", t);

                    applied(t);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the Object t as a parameter to the second Callback function though. If I create a parameter t2 then I will not have the data I need from t.

Comment: @AaronReich Updated my answer.